# Confused between addCookie in response and "Set-Cookie" in header

Tags: servlets, cookies, http-headers

I saw some peoples are using addCookie in response object to set the cookie as below

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", value);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setSecure(true);
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

And some peoples are using "Set-Cookie" in the header to add cookie as below

```
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie","name=" + value + ";Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly");
```

But I am bit confused in this both, what is the difference between both?
And which one we should prefer to use.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, with Servlet api 4.0 being incompatible with SameSite attribute, I would go towards the setHeader/addHeader solution.

More, all request cookies (if not set with sameSite=Strict/Lax/None; Secure) should be added via addHeader('Set-Cookie',...) in the response (to avoid being rejected soon by almost all browsers), like the following

```
    boolean firstHeader = true;
    String sameSite = RequestUtil.isSecure(request) ? "; SameSite=None; Secure" : "; SameSite=Lax";
    for (String header : headers) { // there can be multiple Set-Cookie attributes
        if (firstHeader) {
            response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", String.format("%s; %s", header, sameSite));
            firstHeader = false;
            continue;
        }
        response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", String.format("%s; %s", header, sameSite));
    }
```

If response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie") does not list all expected cookies, try also to check request.getCookies, and use them to add Set-Cookie Header in the response.

Note:
As per my understanding, response.addCookie does not behave similarly as response.addHeader("Set-Cookie")
Indeed, using addCookie, I could not see the corresponding Set-Cookie in response headers...